# AWS Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) EC2. No access to console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, load-balancing, amazon-vpc

I hope to get some help over here. I know this issue is all over the internet, but I think I have a different kind of situation.

My setup is the following:

- Amazon Linux EC2
- The instance has its VPC
- The VPC has its internet gateway
- To enable access I created a TCP Target Group, which is assigned to an Elastic Load Balancer with a 22 port listener.

I had to create the load balancer because it is an abandoned infrastructure by a previous engineer and I had to know how to regain access to the EC2 without affecting the load balancer.

In order to do that, I created a new Load Balancer to gain SSH access.

Once I achieved to get connected to the instance through the load balancer DNS, I received this error, having permission denied.

These are the logs using ssh verbose:

```
soto@LAPTOP-VT374I5C:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv -i soto.pem  ec2-user@ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -p 22
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/soto/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [23.20.173.43] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file soto.pem type -1
debug1: identity file soto.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Q7K81dtMhKJBZUTLXi5ixEAXRIifIlNqy2O1F2Ckwcs
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 23.20.173.43
debug1: Host 'ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/soto/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: soto.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: soto.pem
Load key "soto.pem": Permission denied
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ipfs-api-6fffb2e30dd6fff6.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Things I have already tried:

- Add a username to the ssh connection, which in this case, since it is an Amazon Linux 2, my username us ec2-user.
- Modified the `sshd_config` file, adding the line `PasswordAuthentication yes` and restarting the `sshd` service.
- Tried putty in windows instead of ubuntu, which gave me this error:

[image]

So I am really stuck, I am starting to think that something is wrong with my AWS configuration.

Also, I followed the permissions instructions regarding `chmod 400` to my pem file, so permissions are enough to send the pem.

Thanks a lot in advance for taking a look at this complicated situation, I am more than happy to give more and explained information if need.

Thanks a lot.

PD: I can't access `authorized_keys` on the server-side, since I only have the AWS console as the primary and only access.

Comment: You want to ssh into your Load Balancer?

Comment: SSH should be used to connect _directly to a computer_. It should _not_ be sent via a Load Balancer. This is because you need to establish a connection to a _single_ EC2 instance, while a Load Balancer might distribute the traffic to multiple load balancers. Are you able to **login directly to the EC2 instance**? If not, you might need to update the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance(s).

Comment: Yes, indeed, that was the main problem, I was ignoring the primary principle of accessing to a protected instance, so far, now I can reach the private network through the bastion, but I still have permission issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using a load balancer as a bastion host. I would suggest launching a bastion host into a public subnet in your VPC, SSH-ing into the bastion host, then using the bastion host to SSH into your instance. You'll need to configure your security groups to allow this access.

Comment: Saphiro Thanks a lot for your comment!, I removed the load balancer and the target group, created the bastion and I managed to SSH-ing into the bastion, however, when I try to SSH into my instance through the private IP, I still get the `Permission Denied` error, using the same key pair I used to enter into the bastion.

Comment: That's because you have to use the key pair for that other instance to log into that other instance, not the key pair for the bastion host. If you've lost the instance's key pair, you might try something like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot sir, you saved my day. :D